# Can't connect Django and PostgreSQL (EC2)

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have two servers "App Server" with IP y.y.y.y in which I have a Django Project that I'm trying to connect with another server called "Data Server" with private IP x.x.x.x, I'm getting this error every time I want to make migration:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "y.y.y.y", user "usuario1", database "redesproyecto1", SSL off
```

This is my **settings.py**:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
   'NAME': 'redesproyecto1',
   'USER': 'user',
   'PASSWORD': 'password',
   'HOST': 'x.x.x.x',
   'PORT': '5432',
 }
}
```

And this is my *pg_hba.conf*:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                ident
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.l
host    all     all                  y.y.y.y            trust
host    all     postgres             127.0.0.1/32       md5
host    all     all                  ::1/128            md5
```

Am I missing something?